# Perfect matching and maximum matching

Tags: graph-theory

In a graph where a perfect matching is possible, is that perfect matching also always the maximum matching?

Comment: What does it mean to be a maximum matching?  What does it mean to be a perfect matching?  Do you think you could find a matching with more edges than a perfect matching?

Comment: as the perfect matching covers every node in the graph, then it cannot be extended by another edge. Thus it is maximal and in the case of being perfect, it is maximum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed a perfect matching is an example of a maximum matching; this follows from [the definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29):

> A perfect matching is a matching which matches all vertices of the graph.
>
> A maximum matching is a matching that contains the largest possible number of edges.

If we added an edge to a perfect matching it would no longer be a matching.

To be a perfect matching of a graph $G=(V,E)$, it must have $|V|/2$ edges, and thus $|V|$ must be even.

It is not necessarily the case that it is "the maximum matching", as there might be multiple maximum matchings.  E.g. the blue edges and the orange edges form two different perfect (and maximum) matchings in the graph below:

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's also worth pointing out that the notions of maximum matchings and perfect matchings are equivalent if and only if a perfect matching exists. This means, if a perfect matching exists, then the perfect matchings are exactly the maximum matchings.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G = (V, E)$ be an undirected graph which has a perfect matching $Mp$.

Let $Mm$ be a maximum matching of $G$.

Obviously, $2 |Mp| = |V|$.

Obviously, $2 |Mm| \leq |V|$.

So, $|Mm| \leq \frac{|V|}{2} = |Mp|$.

So, $Mp$ is a maximum matching.